# how to zoom image and text SIMULTANEOUSLY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm confuse in my code how to zoom image. I can able to zoom my text but with that one image is there,that one I'm not able to zoom. Can anyone suggest what to do?
here is my code for text -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var os = $('span').css('font-size');
        var num = parseFloat(os, 10);
        var px = os.slice(-2);
        //if (this.id == 'smaller') {
        $('span').css('font-size', num / 1.1 + px);
        //}
        if (this.id == 'larger') {
            $('span').css('font-size', num * 1.1 + px);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that is not zooming, you simply change the size of font.

Comment: You can`t zoom an image by setting `font-size`. You should probably look for a library that could do it for you.

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142?ref=lvraa&ref=lvraa&clickthrough_id=249560190&redirect_back=true

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/gAkvq/

Comment: mouse over is not require.when ever i'm going to click on zoom-in image then text and image zoom.how much time i'm going to click the link that image and text going to zoom

Comment: @Teemu then how can i make image zoom?

Comment: You can use a plugging -- http://e-smartdev.com/#!jsPluginList/panAndZoomJQuery

Comment: You could use css to set the scale on the container of your image+text so it actually zooms. Another way would be to give the image it's height in EM instead of PX so it changes size based on the text size.

Comment: @ donnywals can you please modify my code and send me.

Comment: Why not to [study it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale) yourself?

Comment: i got it yesterday only.thanks you all for replay and valuable time.